# VTK - Share geometry in multiple vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I'm modifying [this](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/Qt/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt/#download-and-build-sidebysiderenderwindowsqt) example - instead of different geometry I need to render the same geometry in multiple windows. But if I assign the same mapper or actor to multiple renderers I get an error:

> ERROR: In
>   /home/nc/Downloads/VTK-8.1.0/Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkOpenGLActor.cxx,
>   line 107 vtkOpenGLActor (0x24beaf0): failed after Render 1 OpenGL
>   errors detected   0 : (1282) Invalid operation
>
> ERROR: In
>   /home/nc/Downloads/VTK-8.1.0/Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper.cxx,
>   line 1767 vtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper (0x24c7800): failed after
>   UpdateShader 1 OpenGL errors detected   0 : (1282) Invalid operation

[Here](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/OpenGL-errors-upon-move-from-6-3-0-to-7-0-0-td5736732.html) I found the explanation (basically, don't use it in multiple windows):

> With multiple windows it is important to not share actors or mappers
>   in the new OpenGL backend. Each window needs its own mappers and
>   actors. They can share the same data source/readers but not the opengl
>   pieces like actors/mappers.

Does that means I can't share geometry? What are the other way I can reuse a data?

Answer (score 0):

> They can share the same data source/readers but not the opengl pieces
>   like actors/mappers.

Creating multiples actors for the same sources and readers should do the trick.

Comment: Indeed, I can use single source and create multiple actors. I guess it's not performance-heavy object. But I can't use single mapper, and that means I need to repeat filtering (though I'm not sure how expensive is mapping and should I worry at all).

Comment: You can connect the same filtering pipeline to multiple actors. It's kind of expensive for larger objects, but the overhead is unavoidable anyway.